# Entity references aren't loading on object posted to action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework Code First with Migrations (EF 5), C#, and asp.net MVC 3.

I am performing what ought to be a very basic update operation. I have a special circumstance where I need to fetch the original object from the database and then compare it to the modified one. The entity in question references two other entities that are lazy loaded by virtue of the *virtual* keyword.

It took me a while, but I found that I can load the original entity without having it tracked in the context via the "AsNoTracking()" method. That solved one issue.

The issue at hand is that, when I perform a:

```
db.Entry(modifiedObject).Reference(obj => obj.Reference1).Load();
db.Entry(modifiedObject).Reference(obj => obj.Reference2).Load();
```

The object properties aren't updated. Some of the values are posted by the form and bound via the model binder (not a custom one). This is actually done only because the validations for the reference properties were firing and I couldn't find a way to turn them off.

I seem to recall that, in MVC 2, you can't modify the references of an object posted to the action unless you called:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

I've tried that and it hasn't worked. I also seem to recall Phill Haack saying that they changed that in MVC 3.

So my question is, how do I get these references loaded?

Comment: What do you mean by "The object properties aren't updated"? Is `obj.Reference1` not loaded?

Comment: I mean the values for Reference1 that were posted from the page are there, but the page didn't post all of the properties on Reference1, so I want to get the object populated in full and I have the Id for it. So, despite the ...Reference....Load call, the values remain unchanged.